Getting 1-D array (vector) from image collection or multi-band image using Google Earth Engine
I'm using Google Earth Engine and I need to convert an image collection into a single 1-dimensional array containing all pixel values. In my example I will use a multi-band image since image collection --> image is trivial.
Consider a 2 x 2 x 2 image like so:
Band 1



*
x1
x2




y1
2.8
5


y2
3
6.1



Band 2



*
x1
x2




y1
3.2
1


y2
7
4



I want to accumulate these values into an array that no longer has any spatial component, resulting in something like:
var array = [2.8, 5, 3, 6.1, 3.2, 1, 7, 4]

I understand there are multiple ways to "un-weave" these values, and the specific order is not important in my case such that the following would suffice:
var array = [2.8, 3, 5, 6.1, 3.2, 7, 1, 4]


In my specific case my approach so far involves:
a) create an image collection
b) collection.toArray()
c) reducing this Array Image with .toList()
d) taking .values().flatten() of the results
This leaves me with a list, containing lists (I believe), where each element is a single dimension array with a value.

In my efforts to retrieve these nested values I've tried to use functions like the following:
function flattenDeepArray(doubleNestedArray){
  
  function flatArray(arr){return ee.Array(arr).get([0])}
  
  var emptyList = ee.List([]);
  
  emptyList = doubleNestedArray.map(
      function(arr){return ee.Array(ee.Array(arr).get([0])).get([0])}
    );
  
  return emptyList;
}

But this produces the following error:

List (Error) Array.get: Expected 2 coordinates, but found 1

Perhaps the entire approach is wrong. I'm not sure.
How do I achieve this in Google Earth Engine, perhaps using some combination of ee.Array.cat(), project(), reshape(), slice(), etc?

While there might be more efficient ways to do it (also other ways that involve .arraySlice() and ee.Array.cat() as you mentioned), my intuition is to do it without using arrays. That is
//Collection to Image 
var img = Coll.toBands()

// get pixel values: return dictionary of n lists of all pixel values for each band
var pixelVals = img.reduceRegion(
    {reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), geometry: roi, scale: 30});

// convert to list of list that can be flattened
var namdNames = img.bandNames()
var List_of_List = namdNames.map(function(name){return pixelVals.get(name)})
var TheList = List_of_List.flatten()

// cast list to Array
var FinalArray = ee.Array(TheList);

In all cases, as you reduce to list, scaling this approach  will be limited by the region size/number of bands. Here is a full demo code

Thank you very much. Time will tell how this scales, but it certainly works.
